# is there a data cache in the android studio emulator? or is this another issue?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an app and I have a function of it where you can add items to a table, this all works fine, you can add more to each item and delete, the table is saved each time in a stored preference (which is cleared before re-entering info), again all goes in, everything fine.

the problem arises as so, when I press the back button and re-enter the page the stored preferences are successfully loaded back into the table perfectly exactly how it was left, however, when I remove all the items and the last item is removed from the table, I press back and then go back in and the last item has appeared back into the table.
I checked the stored preferences, it is empty and the method that loads the stored preferences does not run, hence I've shown no code because it all works fine, so there is obviously something beyond my code happening.

if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

ok as requested heres my code:

this is intoStore it is from here you click onto the button to the individual container number, the page and code the back button takes me to.

```
package com.apps.storemanager;

import static android.graphics.Color.rgb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IntoStore extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView customerName, address, contactInfo;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences[] containerNumberPreferences;
    Button[] containers;
    TableLayout containerTable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.into_store);

        sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("storeManagerUser" , MODE_PRIVATE);

        customerName = findViewById(R.id.customerNameLabel);
        address = findViewById(R.id.addressLabel);
        contactInfo = findViewById(R.id.contactIfoLabel);

        containerTable = findViewById(R.id.containerTableLayout);


        getIntoStoreCustomer();
    }

    protected void getIntoStoreCustomer(){

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://192.168.0.193/storemanager/getIntoStoreCustomer.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try{

                            //retrieves customer info
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String getCustomerName = jsonObject.getString("Customer Name");
                            String getAddress = jsonObject.getString("Address");
                            String getContactInfo = jsonObject.getString("Contact Info");
                            String getContainers = jsonObject.getString("Containers");

                            //retrieves customers containers
                            String[] getContainerNumber = getContainers.split("\\s+");
                            customerName.setText(getCustomerName);
                            address.setText(getAddress.replace(",", "\n"));
                            contactInfo.setText(getContactInfo);

                            //creates container button array
                            containers = new Button[getContainerNumber.length];
                            containerNumberPreferences = new SharedPreferences[getContainerNumber.length];
                            boolean newRow = false;
                            TableRow row = new TableRow(IntoStore.this);
                            containerTable.addView(row);

                            for(int i = 0; i < containers.length; i++){

                            //create the shared preference per container
                                containerNumberPreferences[i] = getSharedPreferences(getContainerNumber[i], MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = containerNumberPreferences[i].edit();
                                editor.putString("container", getContainerNumber[i]);
                                editor.apply();

                                if(i % 3 == 0) {            //to add 3 containers (buttons) per row

                                    newRow = true;

                                    if(newRow){
                                                            //sets row layout
                                        newRow = false;
                                        row = new TableRow(IntoStore.this);
                                        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                        params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
                                        row.setLayoutParams(params);
                                        containerTable.addView(row);
                                    }
                                }
                                //creates buttons
                                containers[i] = new Button(IntoStore.this);
                                containers[i].setText(getContainerNumber[i]);
                                containers[i].setTextSize(45f);
                                containers[i].setPadding(60, 60,60,60);
                                containers[i].setBackgroundColor((rgb(255,217,25)));
                                TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                                );

                                //adds margin to buttons
                                params.setMargins(10, 10,10,30);
                                containers[i].setLayoutParams(params);
                                row.addView(containers[i],params);

                                containers[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(IntoStore.this.getApplicationContext(), LoadContainer.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("container", ((Button) view).getText().toString());
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                });

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        })
        {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> paramV = new HashMap<>();

                paramV.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("user", ""));

                return paramV;
            }
        };

        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

}
```

this is the code for the individual container number, where the table is added to.

```
package com.apps.storemanager;

import static android.graphics.Color.rgb;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoadContainer extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences containerNumberPreference;
    private TextView containerNumberLabel;
    private EditText itemInput;
    private Float textSize;
    private Button addTenBTN, addTwentyBTN, addItemBTN;
    private TableLayout itemTable;
    private String container;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> ImageCapture;
    private String itemName;
    private Button shutDoor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loadcontainer);

        Bundle getIntent = getIntent().getExtras();
        container = getIntent.getString("container");

        containerNumberPreference = getSharedPreferences(container, MODE_PRIVATE);
        containerNumberLabel = findViewById(R.id.containerNumberLabel);
        containerNumberLabel.setText(containerNumberPreference.getString("container", ""));

        itemTable = findViewById(R.id.loadContainerItemTable);
        itemInput = findViewById(R.id.newItemInput);
        itemInput.setOnClickListener(view -> itemInput.selectAll());

        textSize = 28f;   //text size for item and number

        addTenBTN = findViewById(R.id.addTenCartonBTN);
        addTenBTN.setOnClickListener(view -> addBox(((Button) view).getText().toString()));

        addTwentyBTN = findViewById(R.id.addTwentyCartonBTN);
        addTwentyBTN.setOnClickListener(view -> addBox(((Button) view).getText().toString()));

        addItemBTN = findViewById(R.id.addItemBTN);
        addItemBTN.setOnClickListener(view -> addItem("",""));

        ImageCapture = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){

                        Bundle bundle = result.getData().getExtras();
                        Bitmap bitMap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");

                        saveTempBitmap(bitMap);
                    }

                });

        shutDoor = findViewById(R.id.shutDoorBTN);
        shutDoor.setOnClickListener(view -> saveContainer());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            loadSavedItems();
        }

    }

    /**
     * loads saved items
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    protected void loadSavedItems(){

           Map<String, ?> savedItems = containerNumberPreference.getAll();
           ArrayList<String> itemsAndNumber = new ArrayList<>();
           savedItems.forEach((k, v) -> itemsAndNumber.add(String.valueOf(v)));

           if(itemsAndNumber.size() > 1) {  //1 to skip container number
               for (int i = 1; i < itemsAndNumber.size(); i++) {
                   String item = itemsAndNumber.get(i);
                   String number = itemsAndNumber.get((i+1));
                   addItem(itemsAndNumber.get(i), itemsAndNumber.get(++i));
               }
           }
        }


    /**
     * add item new box 10s and 20s
     */
    protected void addBox(String box){

        boolean existing = addToExistingItem(box);        //search table for duplicate

        if(!existing) {

            TableRow newRow = setTableRow(new TableRow(this));
            TextView newItem = setItemTextView(new TextView(this), box);
            TextView number = setNumberTextView(new TextView(this), "1");
            Button imageButton = setImageButton(new Button(this));
            itemTable.addView(newRow);
            newRow.addView(newItem);
            newRow.addView(number);
            newRow.addView(imageButton);

            updateSharedPreferences();
        }
    }

    /**
     * add new item
     * also parameters for loading shared preferences
     * loadSavedItems() line 92
     */
    protected void addItem(String savedItem, String savedNumber) {

        boolean existing;
        String item = savedItem.isEmpty() ? itemInput.getText().toString().trim() : savedItem;
        String itemNumber = savedNumber.isEmpty() ? "1" : savedNumber;

        if (!item.isEmpty()) {

            existing = addToExistingItem(item);        //search table for duplicate

            if (!existing) {

                TableRow newRow = setTableRow(new TableRow(this));
                TextView newItem = setItemTextView(new TextView(this), item);
                TextView number = setNumberTextView(new TextView(this), itemNumber);
                Button imageButton = setImageButton(new Button(this));
                itemTable.addView(newRow);
                newRow.addView(newItem);
                newRow.addView(number);
                newRow.addView(imageButton);

                updateSharedPreferences();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Item To Load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * finds and adds to existing item
     */
    protected boolean addToExistingItem(String item){

        boolean found = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < itemTable.getChildCount(); i++) {

            TableRow row = (TableRow) itemTable.getChildAt(i);
            TextView text = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
            String getText = text.getText().toString();

            if (getText.equals(item)) {

                found = true;
                TextView numberText = (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
                int update = Integer.parseInt(numberText.getText().toString());
                update++;
                numberText.setText(String.valueOf(update));

                updateSharedPreferences();
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    /**
     * finds and removes item
     */
    protected void removeFromExistingItem(String item) {

        for (int i = 0; i < itemTable.getChildCount(); i++) {

            TableRow row = (TableRow) itemTable.getChildAt(i);
            TextView text = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
            String getText = text.getText().toString();

            if (getText.equals(item)) {

                TextView numberText = (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
                int update = Integer.parseInt(numberText.getText().toString());
                update--;

                final int itemPlace = i;

                if(update == 0){

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadContainer.this);

                    builder.setTitle("Removing Item");

                    builder.setMessage("You Are About To Remove The Item, All images Will be Removed With" +
                                    " It Do You Want To Continue?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, id) -> {

                                itemTable.removeViewAt(itemPlace);
                                row.removeViewAt(itemPlace);
                                updateSharedPreferences();

                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel());

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }else {

                    numberText.setText(String.valueOf(update));
                }

                updateSharedPreferences();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * updates the containers shared preferences
     */
    protected void updateSharedPreferences(){

        String storedItem = "Stored Item ";
        String storedItemNumber = "Stored Item Number ";

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  containerNumberPreference.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.putString("container", containerNumberLabel.getText().toString());

        for(int i = 0; i < itemTable.getChildCount(); i++) {

            TableRow itemRow = (TableRow) itemTable.getChildAt(i);
            TextView itemTextView = (TextView) itemRow.getChildAt(0);
            String item = itemTextView.getText().toString();

            itemTextView = (TextView) itemRow.getChildAt(1);
            String itemNumber = itemTextView.getText().toString();

            editor.putString(storedItem + i, item);
            editor.putString(storedItemNumber + i, itemNumber);
            editor.apply();

        }
    }

    /**
     * gets formatted table row
     */
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    protected TableRow setTableRow(TableRow row){

        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        row.setPadding(0,5,0,0);

        row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private long start;
            private long total;

            //creates touch for item row
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                        start = event.getEventTime();
                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    long time = event.getEventTime();
                    total = time - start;
                    TextView getItem = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
                    String item = getItem.getText().toString();

                    if (total > 500) {      //if touch held it removes 1 of item

                     removeFromExistingItem(item);


                    } else {                //else goes to camera to take photo of item

                        itemName = item;   //name for saved image
                        Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        ImageCapture.launch(takePhoto);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * gets formatted item text view
     */
    protected TextView setItemTextView(TextView itemName, String item){

        itemName.setTextSize(textSize);
        itemName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        itemName.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        itemName.setPadding(15,15,15,15);
        itemName.setBackgroundColor(rgb(0,64,128));
        itemName.setText(item);

        return itemName;
    }

    /**
     * get formatted new number textview
     */
    protected TextView setNumberTextView(TextView tv, String number){

        tv.setTextSize(textSize);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        tv.setPadding(15,15,15,15);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(rgb(0,64,128));
        tv.setText(number);

        return tv;
    }

    /**
     * sets button to view images
     */
    protected Button setImageButton(Button button){

        button.setBackgroundColor(rgb(0,64,128));
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_search_24);
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            TableRow row = (TableRow) button.getParent();
            TextView getTextView = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
            String item = getTextView.getText().toString();

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/Pictures/" + item);
            File[] imageFile = myDir.listFiles();

            ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

            if(imageFile != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imageFile.length; i++) {

                    images.add(imageFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            Intent openImageViewer = new Intent(LoadContainer.this, ImageViewer.class);
            openImageViewer.putStringArrayListExtra("ImageList", images);
            startActivity(openImageViewer);

        });

        return button;
    }

    /**
     * checks for storage permissions
     * @param bitmap
     */

    public void saveTempBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            saveImage(bitmap);
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unable to save file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * saves image to storage
     * @param finalBitmap
     */
    private String saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Pictures/" + itemName);
        myDir.mkdirs();

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fname = itemName + "-" + timeStamp +".jpg";

        File file = new File(myDir, fname);

        try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myDir.toString();
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void saveContainer(){


    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to provide any suggestions if you add your codes with your questions.

Comment: This is unlikely to be a problem with the emulator and more likely to be a problem with your code

Comment: @KenWolf as requested

Comment: @KMRejowanAhmmed as requested

Comment: What have you done to debug your app? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: @dominicoder well ive never used a debugger before if im honest, i have just been doing print statements to find out whats going on, when the last item is removed ive printed to find out what is in the shred preferences, there is nothing and the table is empty, on going back to the page i checked again and they are empty, plus the method to load the shared preferences does not run.

Comment: Then I would suggest starting to learn to use the debugger and stepping through your code line by line. You have _a lot_ going on there, it's very difficult to grok what you're doing, but given the amount of string manipulation and looping happening, you surely have a bug in there somewhere.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question - this kind of feels like you're abusing SharedPreferences as a glorified database. Considering using Room intead. It might even expose or solve the current problem you're having.

Comment: @dominicoder  thanks for the advice, when you're learning this all on the fly as i am right now it can be a bit overwhelming to learn multiple things at once, as i am sure you have experienced yourself but ill try throw that in.

Comment: @dominicoder and ill look into Room, not heard of that before thanks